# jmeter: Executing sampler only during interval of time

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation when I need to refresh a token I am using every 60 seconds, and unfortunately, I can't have multiple thread groups running simultaneously, as I have multiple test cases under the same TestPlan, that I want to execute consecutively.

Is there a way for me to add this RefreshToken sampler, into my thread group, that is not executed during every single thread loop, but rather executed once per number of times or once per number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your request which refreshes the token under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(
def now = vars.getObject('now') ?: vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long 
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - now) >= 55000)    {
    vars.putObject('now'\, System.currentTimeMillis())
    return true
}
else {
   return false
}
,)}
```

[image]

In this case the If Controller's child(ren) will be executed every 55 seconds, put your logic to refresh the token under the If Controller and that would be it.

Comment: It works this way. However, is there a way to execute it only once for all threads in the thread group, as I am re-using token between all users in the thread group

Comment: Add another condition like `if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 1) { // the remaining code here }`. `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article to learn more about what do these JMeter API shorthands like `ctx`, `vars`, `props`, etc. mean